# How do I create a deep learning model by concatenating two hidden layers of the same output shape of Resnet and VGG-16 using TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to create a CNN model using the concatenation of hidden layers two pretrained models Resnet and VGG16

Answer (score 0):

After you define model, checkout these pretrained models layers by model.summary(), then when you define layer, try to take output of that layer in this way; first get the model.get_layer('layer_name') and then take its output by layer.output, and now concatenate the outputs of the layers that you have defined before.

Comment: I did this "https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/w46dJ8knYP/". But getting error " Layer "model_5" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors.".Could you please check it out

Comment: I don't know which architecture did you use as pretrained model, but as you know in these cases when concatenate two layers outputs on the axis = -1, so the outputshape of these two layers must have been in the same shape except for the axis = -1, so notice that when you get summary of these pretrained models and checkout specified layers output shape.